# Update query INNER JOIN mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

If I want to make an update query using `INNER JOIN`, how do I do in this case:

I have a `users` table & `user_settings` table. `users` contains column `id` and `user_settings` contains column `userid`. I want to do like:

```
UPDATE users_settings SET commets = 0 WHERE email = "$email";
```

But `user_settings` does not contain `email`, so I want to pick the `email` from the `users` table where the `id` is `userid`.

Comment: Provide table schemas for both users and user_settings @Omega Cebbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query. it will work

```
UPDATE users_settings SET commets = 0 WHERE userid
IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = "$email");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE user_settings s 
INNER JOIN users u ON s.userid=u.id
SET s.commets = 0 WHERE u.email = "$email";
```

Note: There should be no users with the same e-mail in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

The following will be helpful

```
UPDATE US SET US.Comments = 0
FROM User_settings US,  Users U
WHERE US.Userid = U.id
AND U.email = 'emailid'
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN`s are slightly better in terms of performance than `SUB QUERIES`. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

So instead of using this -

```
UPDATE users_settings SET commets = 0 WHERE userid
IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = "$email");
```

I would suggest this using `INNER JOIN` -

```
UPDATE users_settings 
SET commets = 0 
FROM user_settings 
INNER JOIN users 
on users.id = user_settings.userid   --JOIN CONDITION
WHERE users.email = "$email" ;       --SELECTION/SLICING CRITERION
```

Hope this helps.